# Reference for idempotent rings

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, reference-works

In the wiki page of [algebraic ring without multiplicative identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)) appears the definition of idempotent ring as a weakening of unital ring.

Does any have a reference of  where or why this concept appear?

Comment: "where or why" is hard to interpret here.  Are you asking for a text or other reference for studying the properties of idempotent rings, or are you asking for an nontrivial example of one?

Comment: Both please. It is hard to find reference.

Comment: Why they were defined, and where they defined. Thanks

Comment: While I've seen the condition $R^2=R$ as a regularity condition for rings without identity, I can't say I've seen a text solely about them. Maybe there's a paper that focuses on them..

Comment: Is not the concept of boolean ring, is idempotent as an ideal.